# problem with flash message in yii2 DbSession

Tags: php, mysql, session, yii2

i use yii\web\DbSession class for session component.When I use Flash, the message is displayed but the flash is not removed And is displayed again on other pages, If I use yii\web\Session class, the problem will be solved. The problem is only when I use the DbSession class.

my code: (use in main layout)

```
<?php
$session = Yii::$app->session;

if($session->hasFlash(‘success’)) {
$msg=$session->getFlash(‘success’);
$this->registerJs("
noty(’".trim($msg)."’,‘success’);
“);
}
if($session->hasFlash(‘error’)) {
$msg=$session->getFlash(‘error’);
$this->registerJs(”
noty(’".trim($msg)."’,‘error’);
");
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash messages can be set using the [setFlash](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-session#setFlash()-detail)() Method

Add below code in your controller file.

Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success','Processed successfuly');

The first argument of setFlash method could be one of the following  error,danger,success,info,warning

And this will determine the color of the flash message

For the displaying part, you need place the following code in your layout file -

```
<?= common\widgets\Alert::widget() ?>
```

Comment: tnx, but I know this and I defined it in the controller class.

Comment: @Mohamad Mahdi Rezaei, I have just edited my answer, please do check it.  And do comment if it has been helpful or not?

Comment: tnx, I tried this widget before, but this widget did not solve my problem. I think the problem is not with the code because it works well with the php session class but does not work with the DbSession class.

Comment: check this https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/12332, may be it will help you.

Comment: This bug was fixed by disabling the log component.

Comment: this doesn't work for me when using dbsession, any idea why?

Comment: @MohamadMahdiRezaei have to disable logs when using DB sessions? this? `'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],`